# Как осуществить безопасный поиск по одному столбцу?

Tags: php, pdo

Как осуществить безопасный поиск по одному столбцу? `php pdo`

Как Вам такой код?

```
$query='SELECT title FROM tab1 WHERE title LIKE :search ORDER BY date DESC';
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':search' => '%'.$searchVal.'%'));
```

Comment: Слишком обще. Где конкретная проблема?

Comment: Нет проблемы, пока что нет никакого кода. Просто раньше я не использовал pdo как только начал знакомится с php и нашел простенький код где в запросе было как-то `select * ..........mysql_escape_string(%.LIKE.%)` - вроде так. Но такой код я читал не безопасный с оператором `LIKE`

Comment: и подумал может мне кто нибудь на словах, или с примером. Сам я думаю сделать это с подготовленным выражением, так правильно будет и поиском?

Comment: @Visman, отредактировал пост

Comment: Сами по себе подготовленные выражения уже безопасны, так как переменные для запроса отделены от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это вполне безопасно.
Я бы только не разводил лишнюю писанину с именованными плейсхолдерами.
Ну и поправлю предыдущего оратора на тему получения результатов поиска, которых явно будет не один

```
$query='SELECT title FROM tab1 WHERE title LIKE ? ORDER BY date DESC';
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array('%'.$searchVal.'%'));
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Comment: верно, не один, и вопрос если не против, почему `?` а не `:search` ?

Answer (score 1):

Вывести значение 1ой колонки по идее можно так:

```
$query = 'SELECT title FROM tab1 WHERE title LIKE :search ORDER BY date DESC';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':search' => '%'.$searchVal.'%'));
echo $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Будет тебе в ответе `title`